# yii multiple check box as array not saved in database

Tags: php, yii

I am new to yii framework.

```
            <div class="col-md-5">
          <input id="ytAdd_Employee_varHobbies" type="hidden" value="" name="Add_Employee[varHobbies]">
          <span id="Add_Employee_varHobbies">
          <input id="Add_Employee_varHobbies_0" value="5" type="checkbox" name="Add_Employee[varHobbies][]">
          <label for="Add_Employee_varHobbies_0">BaseBall</label>
          <br>
          <input id="Add_Employee_varHobbies_1" value="2" type="checkbox" name="Add_Employee[varHobbies][]">
          <label for="Add_Employee_varHobbies_1">Football</label>
          <br>
          <input id="Add_Employee_varHobbies_2" value="4" type="checkbox" name="Add_Employee[varHobbies][]">
          <label for="Add_Employee_varHobbies_2">Hockey</label>
          <br></div>
```

Here i have multiple checboxes as array in the name of `Add_Employee[varHobbies][]`

In the controller i saved the form as

```
 $model->attributes=$_POST['Add_Employee'];
         //print_r($model);exit;
         $image_upload=$model->Image = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'Image'); 

         if( $model->validate() && $model->save())
         {  }
```

By using `$model->save()` all my fields are saved properly but this check box saved as array.

In my model i set the rules as

```
array('varHobbies', 'type', 'type' => 'array', 'allowEmpty' => false),
```

I want to save the hobbies as 1,2,3 and so on....

But it is saved as 'array'.

How to fix this?

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your model to save hobbies as a string:

```
protected function beforeSave() {
    parent::beforeSave();
    $this->varHobbies = implode(',', $this->varHobbies);
    return $this;
}
```